# What do "single-entry" and "single-exit" mean for a statement?

Tags: loops, conditional-statements, programming-languages, control-structure

From [An Integrated Approach to Software Engineering
By Pankaj Jalote](https://books.google.com/books?id=Hi_vBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA359&dq=Clearly%2C%20no%20meaningful%20program%20can%20be%20written%20as%20a%20sequence%20of%20simple&pg=PA359#v=onepage&q=Clearly,%20no%20meaningful%20program%20can%20be%20written%20as%20a%20sequence%20of%20simple&f=false)

> Clearly, no meaningful program can be written as a sequence of simple
>   statements without any branching or repetition (which also involves
>   branching). So, **how is the objective of linearizing the control ﬂow
>   to be achieved?** By making use of **structured constructs**. In
>   structured programming, a statement is not a simple assignment
>   statement, it is a structured statement. The key property of a
>   structured statement is that it has a **single-entry** and a
>   **single-exit**. That is, during execution, the execution of the (structured) statement starts from one deﬁned point and the execution
>   terminates at one deﬁned point. With single-entry and single-exit
>   statements, we can view a program as a sequence of (structured)
>   statements. And if all statements are structured statements, then
>   during execution, the sequence of execution of these statements will
>   be the same as the sequence in the program text. Hence, by using
>   single-entry and single-exit statements, the correspondence between
>   the static and dynamic structures can be obtained.
>
> **The most commonly used single-entry and single-exit statements** are
>
> ```
> Selection: if B then S1 else S2
> if B then S1
>
> Iteration: While B do S
> repeat S until B
>
> Sequencing: S1; S2; S3;...
> ```

What do "single-entry" and "single-exit" mean in a structured statement?

Why are statements listed at the end are single-entry and single-exit?
For example, in `if B then S1 else S2`, why is it single exit, given it can terminates at either `S1` or `S2`?

Can you give a statement which is not single entry?

Can you given a statement which is not single exit?

Comment: It doesn't terminate "at either S1 or S2", it terminates at a single point which is after both.

Comment: Thanks. 
Can you give a statement which is not single entry?
Can you given a statement which is not single exit?

Answer (score 3):

In many languages, the only statements that do not have a single entry are those which happen to contain labels for use with `goto` or `switch` statements located outside them, and the only statements that do not have a single exit are those which contain a `goto` to an outside location, trigger an exception, or otherwise force stack unwinding.  Note that for any *particular* call of a function, the only "normal" exit point will be the code immediately following that call.

The notion of single entry/single exit may be unclear to those who have never worked with code that didn't use such an approach.  Examples of the latter may be found when writing code for the platforms like the Atari 2600 where RAM space is often at an absolute premium.  If a piece of code will be invoked from the code that shows the title screen, or from within the game logic, and there one can't afford the two bytes of stack space necessary for a subroutine-call instruction, it would not be uncommon to jump to the code (rather than using a "JSR" [jump to subroutine] instruction), and have the code exit by checking whether a game is in progress and jumping back to the appropriate spot in the "show title screen" or "perform game logic" code.  Such a design may be awkward to maintain if it becomes necessary to invoke it from more places in the code, but such techniques may be necessary if RAM is really tight (e.g. one only has 128 bytes total, as on the Atari 2600).